# Xamarin ObservableCollection

Tags: xamarin

Olá!

Estou usando Xamarin e quando quero carregar e exibir na tela uma lista de objetos eu uso `ObservableCollection` para fazer a página carregar só após o conteúdo ser carregado. Mas em um dos retornos da WebService eu recebo apenas uma string.

Qual propriedade eu uso para carregar o conteúdo antes de carregar a página com apenas uma string?

Comment: O ideal seria você adicionar um [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do que já tentou e indicar o [problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) que está tendo.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, sua pergunta está meio confusa, mas no que eu entendi você quer carregar uma lista em uma página.

O ObservableCollection é uma lista que emite uma notificação quando ela é alterada, ou seja, quando está trabalhando com uma listView e você usa um ObservableCollection como fonte de dados, significa que quando você insere um objeto nesta lista, o ObservableCollection vai lançar uma notificação e sua ListView irá atualizar com o novo objeto.

No seu caso, pelo que eu entendi, você quer carregar a página apenas quando a ListView estiver preenchida. Para fazer isso é só preencher a lista no construtor da tela, mas não é uma boa prática, pois se a lista for grande, pode demorar a abrir a tela, com isso, a aplicação fica travada.

Eu aconselharia você a utilizar paginação em sua lista e preenche-lá inicialmente no método OnApearing, pois ele é executado quando sua view aparece. Lembrando de usar métodos Async, pois assim você evita que o processamento ocorra na Thread principal, causando assim, uma experiência travada para o usuário .

Comment: Acho que não consegui me expressar bem mas, já consegui resolver. Eu estava recebendo os dados da ViewModel no construtor do arquivo .cs da View. Apenas coloquei o retorno da ViewModel no OnAppearing() e funcionou. Obrigado.